# Powershell is missing the terminator: " and Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition

Tags: powershell

I am new on powershell and I have an issue. I am trying to make a script that cleans all my directories older than 30 days, but when I run it, it breaks. Does anyone know what problem I have?

```
$fromNDays = $args[0]
$cutOffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$fromNDays) 
$directoriesToDelete =  Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Attributes Directory -Filter r* | Where-Object LastWriteTime -le $cutOffDate
echo "deleting from $cutOffDate"
cd $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)
cd ..\..
pwd
Foreach($directoryToDelete in $directoriesToDelete)
{
    if($directoryToDelete.Name -ne "ReleaseRootMapping")
    {
        try
        {
            echo "Deleting directory $directoryToDelete"
            Remove-Item –path $directoryToDelete.FullName -Force -Recurse
        }
        catch
        {
            echo "Failed deleting $directoryToDelete.FullName"
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I have when it runs is:

echo "Failed deleting $directoryToDelete.FullName"
+                                                          ~

2020-03-09T09:55:23.3827859Z ##[error]The string is missing the terminator: ".

deleteReleaseDirectoryFrom30.ps1:12 char:5

2020-03-09T09:55:23.3832466Z ##[error]+     {
2020-03-09T09:55:23.3836221Z ##[error]Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.

This error apears on line 12, 23, 8 and 10

Comment: Can you please copy the error into your question. If you don't show us that we can't help

Comment: Hi @Nicicalu, I edit my question. Thank you for the support

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $cutOffDate }` ? Also, you don't show where variable `$path` comes from, and to me, `cd $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)` is a mystery.. Is _Agent_ a variable and then why does it not have the dollar sign in front? In the catch block, change to `echo "Failed deleting $($directoryToDelete.FullName)"`

Comment: You should add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Remove-Item` cmdlet in order to capture non-terminating errors too in the catch block. Also, please change the line in the catch block from `echo "Failed deleting $directoryToDelete.FullName"` to just **throw** in order to see the real exception message instead of the string you provided.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the script doesn't know, that `$directoryToDelete.FullName` is a variable.
So first, put them one into brackets:

```
try{
    echo "Deleting directory ${directoryToDelete}"
    Remove-Item –path ${directoryToDelete.FullName} -Force -Recurse
}
catch
{
    echo "Failed deleting ${directoryToDelete.FullName}"
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, then I won't be able to help you. I will delete my answer in a few minutes :/

Answer (score 0):

As described here : https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1308, there is this problem with PS and VSCode.

According to the answers on GitHub, a solution is to paste your code in the Powershell ISE (you can do a simple Windows search for that), and save using it. Then you can continue coding with VsCode or anything else you use.

Hope this helps you, even though I'm a bit late here...